# Question regarding the shape of a probability distribution given a specific condition on its standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ denote a random variable, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose the following condition to be true, where

\begin{equation}
P(X=\mu+\sigma)=P(X=\mu-\sigma)=0.5
\end{equation}

Is there any specific shape or probability distribution that would satisfy this?

I believe this is saying that all possible values of $X$ lie within one standard deviation, if this is true, what else does it imply about $X$?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example.
$$X=
\begin{cases}
1 & p=0.5 \\
-1 & 1-p=0.5 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Mean and variance:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=0$$
$$\mathbb{V}[X]=p(1)^2+(1-p)(-1)^2=1$$
It holds that
$$P(X=\mu+\sigma)=P(X=0+1)=P(X=1)=0.5$$
$$P(X=\mu-\sigma)=P(X=0-1)=P(X=-1)=0.5$$

Comment: Thanks, and just a follow up, what would be the case if X is a continuous random variable?

Comment: If $X$ is continuous then $P(X=x)=0,\forall x$, so your premise cannot be satisfied.